# EditText with bottom border only

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I am trying to make a custom edit text that has only a bottom border. I have tried this code and set it as background:

```
<item android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/lightGray"/>
            <padding android:left="12dp" android:right="12dp" android:top="12dp" android:bottom="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

and the border is exactly how I want it but it is placed in the middle of the edit text and not at the bottom. How can I solve this?

Comment: Check below answer, it will work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a bottom bordered edittext by using  ;
the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image: The Screen Shot of the above Xml set as background of edittex]

Answer (score 0):

can you check this, modify as per need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="@dimen/minus10dp"
        android:right="@dimen/minus10dp"
        android:top="@dimen/minus10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/dp2"
                android:color="@color/orangey_red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-10dp" android:left="-2dp" android:right="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/lightGray" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```